# Not able to apply validation in the database first approach in asp.net mvc System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException:

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have made a small mvc application and was not trying to implement validation on it. For this I tried using this tutorial

http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/implement-validation-in-asp.net-mvc

I had done the exact thing but getting an error

My code is as follows

Model Class

```
namespace Bittu2
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public partial class student1
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(30)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Branch { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Mobile Number:")]
       [Required(ErrorMessage = "Mobile Number is required.")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([0-9]{10})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Mobile Number.")]
        public Nullable<int> Mobile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`create` Action method in `Home Controller`

```
private StudentDemoEntities studentDemoEntities = new StudentDemoEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var s = from student1 in studentDemoEntities.student1 select student1;
            return View(s);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(String Name, String Branch, int Mobile)
        {
            student1 stud = new student1();
            stud.Name = Name;
            stud.Branch = Branch;
            stud.Mobile = Mobile;


                if(ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    studentDemoEntities.student1.Add(stud);
                    studentDemoEntities.SaveChanges();  //getting exception here. System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: 'Validation failed for one or more entities. 

                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
               return View();


        }
```

My `create` view

```
model Bittu2.student1

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home"))
    {
        <table>
            <tr>
                 <td>
                     @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                 </td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Branch)

                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Branch)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Branch, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mobile)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
                <td>

 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Mobile)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Mobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    }

    <p>

    </p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")


</body>
</html>
```

I was supposed to get message on the view itself if entered incorrectly but I don't understand what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass a model to the create action instead passing several strings. Pass `student1` class to the `Create` action and after that call `ModelState.IsValid` to check model is valid or not.

```
public ActionResult Create(student1 student)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        studentDemoEntities.student1.Add(student);
        studentDemoEntities.SaveChanges()

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(student);
}
```

you can also check which property is not valid when you call `SaveChanges`:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    studentDemoEntities.student1.Add(stud);
    try
    {
        return studentDemoEntities.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
    {
        foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        return Index(student);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is happening if I pass string? and then creating class object and adding to it. I mean what is wrong with it?

Comment: you have check each parameter by yourself, `if(Name == null) {ModelState.AddModelError("Name is required")} ...` and then call `ModlState.IsValid`